# MySQLi Pagination

Tags: php, mysqli

I have used code for pagination previously that was using the MySQL extension and I have attempted to modify it to use the MySQLi extension but can't get it working.

Is there something obvious with the code?

```
<?php

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");

$per_page = 20;

$pages_query = mysqli_query("SELECT count('company_id') AS company_count FROM companies ");

$pages = ceil(mysqli_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM companies ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$i = 0;

$dyn_table = "<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '></th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '>Company Name</th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '>Address</th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '></th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '></th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '></th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '>Post Code</th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; '>Telephone No</th>
    <th style='background-color:#FD8023; color:white; text-align:center; '>Status</th>
    </tr>";

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    if ($i % 2 == 0) {

$dyn_table .= "<tr>
    <td style=' background-color: #FD8023; '><a href='../company_amend/?company_id=".$rows['company_id']."'><i class=' alt fa fa-pencil'></i></a></td>
    <td>".$rows['company_name']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_1']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_2']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_3']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_4']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['post_code']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['telephone_no']."</td>";

$status=$rows['status'];

if ($status=="1") {
$dyn_table .= "<td style='text-align:center; color:#008000; '><i class='fa fa-check'></i></td>";
} else {
$dyn_table .= "<td style='text-align:center; color:#FF0000; '><i class='fa fa-times'></i></td>";
}

$dyn_table .= "</tr>";

    } else {

$dyn_table .= "<tr>
    <td style=' background-color: #FD8023; '><a href='../company_amend/?company_id=".$rows['company_id']."'><i class=' alt fa fa-pencil'></i></a></td>
    <td>".$rows['company_name']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_1']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_2']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_3']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['address_4']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['post_code']."</td>
    <td>".$rows['telephone_no']."</td>";

$status=$rows['status'];

if ($status=="1") {
$dyn_table .= "<td style='text-align:center; color:#008000; '><i class='fa fa-check'></i></td>";
} else {
$dyn_table .= "<td style='text-align:center; color:#FF0000; '><i class='fa fa-times'></i></td>";
}

$dyn_table .= "</tr>";

    }
    $i++;

}

mysqli_close($conn);

$dyn_table .= "</table>";

echo $dyn_table;

echo "<center>";
if ($page>1){ $first = 1; echo "<a href='?page=".$first."' class='button radius tiny'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i> First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
if ($page>1){ $previous = $page -1; echo "<a href='?page=".$previous."' class='button radius tiny'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i> Prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
if ($page>=1 && $page < $pages){ $next = $page +1; echo "<a href='?page=".$next."' class='button radius tiny'>Next <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}
if ($page>=1 && $page < $pages){ $last = $pages; echo "<a href='?page=".$last."' class='button radius tiny'> Last <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i></a>";}
echo "</center>";

?>
```

dbconnect.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "server";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 ?>
```

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks,

John

Comment: Your question is very vague. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: mysqli_query works with the db and the query like `mysqli_query($conn, "query as string")`. $pages_query doesnt work here

Comment: @rlanvin - it returns no results not even an error message

Comment: @Hearner - I have tried $pages_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count('company_id') AS company_count FROM companies "); but still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "no results"? A blank page? Have you enabled error reporting? Have you checked PHP error logs?

Comment: @rlanvin - no results, blank page, nothing appears. I don't know how to enable error reporting and have no access to PHP error logs.

Comment: Enable error reporting using this code  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and check it.

Comment: Thanks @MansoorH - the error is: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Comment: Because `mysqli_result` is very bad. Use `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because of `mysqli_result` (your error). Use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead which is an array, so here is how you have to use it

```
$per_page = 20;

$pages_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count('company_id') AS company_count FROM companies ");

$pages = ceil(mysqli_fetch_array($pages_query)['company_count'] / $per_page);
```

`Mysqli_fetch_array` returns array of all results. In your case there is only one result which is `company_count`. So simply put what you want to use in brackets

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you so much for your help, working perfectly!

Comment: Did you understand how it works ? It's the most important

Comment: yes, It was obviously useful knowing the error message and once I googled that and saw that mysqli_result() does not exist and that I should to use mysqli_fetch_array instead I was on my way but could not work out the correct syntax. Thanks again.